# How to correctly handling nuget dependencies without pollution main project with unnecessary dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-spec

**Issue:**

- "Could not load file or assembly Razorlight...." during attempting to intaracting with CustomProject instance within the main solution

**Prerequisites:**

- The *main solution* consumes *custom project* as nuget package
- The *custom project* nuget package builded up as single dll (customProject.dll) with embedded references to dependent assemblies (etc. razorlight)
- The *custom project* builded up as a single file due to `includeReferencedProjects = true` property from nugetpacksettings or nuspec configuration (not sure on 100 %)
- Custom project nuget package has *nuscpec* configuration, to config output as single dll file
- The *custom project* has dependency on 3-th party nuget packages with their dependencies (PackageA, PackageB .. etc.)
- There no any other dlls in the main solution `bin/Debug` folder except *customProject.dll* after build

**Intenstions:** (Is it possible ?)

- Manange the issue (*Could not load file or assembly Razorlight*). Thus have all nessacary dll in the *MainSolution* `\bin` folder in runtime (e.g razorlight.dll)
- Not pollution the *Main solution* `package.config` & `.csproj` with a huge amount of unnessacary dependencies/ references from dependent packages (Razorlight, packageA, PackageB ... etc).
- Wouldn't like to install Razorliaght or Itext7 nuget in the Main solution directly

[image]

Comment: The main solution doesn't (usually) need to reference sub-dependent nugets, but they will still appear in your bin folder, as the customproject won't run without it.

Comment: There no any other dlls in the main solution bin/Debug folder except customProject.dll after build. It may happen due to includeReferencedProjects = true, but I'm not sure. So, do you insist that all dependent  dll (e.g. razorlight.dll) should be appear on main solution /bin folder after build ?

Comment: They should definitely appear in the main solution bin folder, otherwise how would the code run?  (which is what you are seeing).

Comment: yes - so do I, but what is wrong then, where I can look into ? It's just blow my mind